# How to transfer image data from node.js to html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, electron

I am trying to build a demo which is a node.js C++ plugin. In node.js i am getting a bitmap, which is in ARGB format, and i need to pass that to html5 canvas. I am trying to find the most efficient way to do this, because it's painfully slow.

Currently I do the following:

```
--- in node.js ---
- Convert ARGB to RGBA (because ImageData accepts that format)
- Create v8::ArrayBuffer (wrapper over the underlying buffer)
- Create v8::Uint8ClampedArray (wrapper over the array buffer)
- Return an object which has the Uint8ClampedArray, width and height

--- in the browser ---
- Get the result from my function
- Create ImageData instance with the specified width and height
- Loop over all bytes in the Uint8ClampedArray and copy them to the image data
- context.putImageData(image_data, 0, 0);
```

I am pretty sure that there must be more optimal way to do this. It is not a problem to somehow keep alive the buffer in the addin, but i would like to at least avoid the byte-by-byte copy of the buffer to the image data.

I am also not sure why if i try to use the ImageData constructor that takes Uint8ClampedArray as first parameter blows up. In such a case, i am just getting:
v8::Object::GetAlignedPointerFromInternalField(). Error:Not a Smi

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [resterize js](http://cburgmer.github.io/rasterizeHTML.js/) to bind data in canvas. I used this it works fast even for large size of images.